What are all the possible flaws in The Thaumaturge?
I have finished the game, and I do not want to start over, but I'm curious. There are twelve flaws in total in the game UI, your main one, Pride, and then eleven more. I searched the internet for the missing ones, and I got some info, but it is incomplete. As far as I understand the flaws can be summed up by this table:




Flaw
Owner
Salutor
Dimension
Quest




1
Pride
Wiktor
Upyr
Heart



2
Vehemence
Vesna
Bukavac
Deed
Shadows of Sins Past


3
Recklesness
Danis
Lelek
Mind
Bastards of the Night


4
Scheming
Sofya
Velels
Word
The Reptilian Bash


5
Selfishness
Petya
---
Mind
The Price of Friendship


6
Fanaticism
Wlodzimierz
---
Word
They're Alive


7
Fright
Szymek
---
Heart
The Devil's Gambit


8
Negligence
Kajetan
Morana
Mind
Horses In the Sky


9
Audacity
Leila
Djinn
Heart
Fearless


10
???
Ligia
Golem
Deed
Clay Ambitions


11
Demagoguery
Edek
Krampus
Word
A rod for the hero


12
???
Skalon
---
???
Close to the Apple Tree



My question is: what are the missing flaws, and what dimension do they belong to?
In particular, what is Ligia's flaw and what is Skalon's flaw?

Ligia's flaw: Ambition
General Skalon's flaw: Malice (Dimension Deed)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It is quite possible that the only supportying source could be screenshots from the game itself, or some youtube videos. I have not found any of those (with the answer) while writing the question, so they could be quite tricky to find. As such, if this answer is correct, which is likely, it may be challenging to find additional supporting information. Thank you for the asnwer!
